# How can I style a a table according to a value coming from SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a very tiny and simple tickiting system for my repair shop, its just an HTML page with a form to record the cutomer information and a SQL database and a page to show data.

in the page that shows the data, the maintenance guy will have make change on some fields to show the progress of the case.
I want to change the color of a row in the table according to the progress.

for example, I want a row colored green when the maintenance guy sets progress to Done state .

I tried everything I know in PHP and couldn't solve so please tell where to search about that ... Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Does the maintenance guy type in 'Done' or does he select it from a select list?  What happens if he misspells it?  Where does the color information come from?   Basically, you need to set the background color on the entire row (tr).

Comment: If you want this to happen immediately, without submitting the form, you have to do it in JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create style in css for every class (for each status).
Define class style for Done, In-Progress etc..
Then, add class to each row of data according to the status.

```css
.done{
  background-color: green;
}
.notdone{
  background-color: red;
}
.inprogress{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr class="done"><td>Reading 1 Jurnal</td><td>Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="done"><td>Reading 10 Jurnal</td><td>Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="done"><td>Reading 50 Jurnal</td><td>Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="notdone"><td>Reading 100 Jurnal</td><td>Not Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="done"><td>Write Literature Review of 10 Jurnal</td><td>Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="inprogress"><td>Write Literature Review of 50 Jurnal</td><td>In-Progress</td></tr>
  <tr class="notdone"><td>Write Critical Review of 50 Jurnal</td><td>Not Done</td></tr>
  <tr class="notdone"><td>Write Critical Review of 100 Jurnal</td><td>Not Done</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can use add class using (jquery)
e.g.

`$(selector).addClass("done");`

or if you do not want to use jquery, you can add it using php,
e.g.

```
<?php
 if($row[$i][1]=="Done"){ $class="done";}
 else if($row[$i][1]=="In Progress"){ $class="inprogress";}
 else if($row[$i][1]=="Not Done"){ $class="notdone";}
 ?>

 <tr class="<?php $class;?>"><td>Reading 1 Jurnal</td><td>Done</td></tr>
```

Where:

- `$row[$i]` is expected data from database
- that code were in loop of data
- Both `<td>` is supposedly data from database (assume you already get from database)

Comment: You can also use style tag in html to define css style (if you want)
use the same concept of php part to add class.